# gdb target remote:1234 connection timeout linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, gdb

I want to debug linux kernel, which is running on qemu using gdb.
    i ran the kernel on qemu using below command.

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel ../bzimage -initrd ... / *.image -nographic 
--append "console =ttys0 init =/init" -s -S &

now i want to run gdb
gdb vmlinux
(kernel symbols are loaded)
gdb target remote:1234

now i am getting below error
remote:1234 connection timeout.
```

Comment: Here is a minimal runnable setup that supports GDB on QEMU and just works: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8815312cad053d0284c4d91bfbf36a1e9ea207af#qemu-buildroot-setup

Answer (score 3):

I saw the same problem.  Somehow running qemu in the background (with the trailing '&') won't work.  You just have to run gdb from another shell.

Answer (score 2):

You got the host to connect to wrong.
It should be

```
target remote :1234
```

Note the space. Otherwise gdb parses the command as a host named `remote`.

Also, try running QEMU without the ampersand character.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  i even tried with your approach,                     Reading symbols from /home/ayl5kor/Desktop/work/OSADL-LINUX/check/linux-3.14.50/vmlinux...done.
(gdb) target remote :1234
:1234: Connection timed out.